# Delay a for loop for a certain number of seconds

Tags: java

I have a for loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  //Do something

 //Delay for 5 seconds then go to the next iteration of loop
 }
```

How do I specify a delay in Java?

Comment: `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5)`.

Comment: @beresfordt that method is not reliable: *subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers*

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza whether that matters depends on what the OP wants to do. A `ScheduledExecutorService` might be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

The default way to do it is Thread.sleep(5000). Usually it is used in the context of [multithreading](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm).

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    //Do something

    //Delay for 5 seconds then go to the next iteration of loop
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would say that no sensible multi-threading uses `Thread.sleep`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider it can be used as a way to sample the time until you are sure a certain amount of time has passed, right?

Comment: I am currently working on a head tracking system that makes the gyroscope more stable with visual technology. Because the visual procedure has high performance costs, I consider letting it run in a separate thread and sleep for a while.

Comment: @k_g `ScheduledExecutorService` is used to schedule tasks to happen in the future.